Facing issues with adding text over a video as watermark using ffmpeg in Laravel
I am facing issues with adding text over a video as a watermark using pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg.
Where am I going wrong?
Code:
$format = new X264();
$format->setAudioCodec('aac');
$format->setVideoCodec('libx264');
$format->setKiloBitrate(0);

$localPath = '/' . $this->video->id . '.mp4';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg::fromDisk("public")
          ->open($localPath)
          ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
            $filters->custom("drawtext=fontfile=S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/public/webfonts/arial.TTF:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24");
          })
          ->export()
          ->toDisk('public')
          ->inFormat($format)
          ->save("watermark_video_added.mp4");

And this is error I am getting:
[2024-08-25 08:53:25] local.INFO: ffprobe running command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -help -loglevel quiet  
[2024-08-25 08:53:25] local.INFO: ffprobe executed command successfully  
[2024-08-25 08:53:25] local.INFO: ffprobe running command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4" -show_streams -print_format json  
[2024-08-25 08:53:25] local.INFO: ffprobe executed command successfully  
[2024-08-25 08:53:25] local.INFO: ffmpeg running command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -ss 00:00:01.00 -i "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4" -vframes 1 -f image2 "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/RzBnC8ZESC40iRSfOuED66cb37513ccd11724594001-poster.jpg"  
[2024-08-25 08:53:26] local.INFO: ffmpeg executed command successfully  
[2024-08-25 08:53:26] local.INFO: ffmpeg running command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4" -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/public/webfonts/arial.TTF:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24[out]" "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/watermark_video_added.mp4"  
[2024-08-25 08:53:26] local.INFO: ffprobe running command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4" -show_format -print_format json  
[2024-08-25 08:53:26] local.INFO: ffprobe executed command successfully  
[2024-08-25 08:53:26] local.ERROR: ffmpeg failed to execute command C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4" -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/public/webfonts/arial.TTF:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24[out]" "S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/watermark_video_added.mp4": ffmpeg version 2024-08-21-git-9d15fe77e3-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 34.100 / 59. 34.100
  libavcodec     61. 11.100 / 61. 11.100
  libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/143.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2024-08-25T10:28:56.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:05.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6491 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1906x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 953:480], 6317 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2024-08-25T10:28:56.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2024-08-25T10:28:56.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020e99b5f0c0] No option name near '/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/public/webfonts/arial.TTF:text=Stack Overflow:fontcolor=white:fontsize=24'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020e99b5f0c0] Error parsing a filter description around: [out]
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020e99b5f0c0] Error parsing filterchain '[in]drawtext=fontfile=S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/public/webfonts/arial.TTF:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24[out]' around: [out]
Error opening output file S:/Freelancer/version58trials/version58trials/storage/app/public/watermark_video_added.mp4.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

What I tried, is manipulating that filter function but I couldn't make it.
For your knowledge,the video paths and font path is correct the only issue is with ffmpeg adding watermark text logic.

try to escape : → S\\\:/Freelancer/...

@БаярГончикжапов yeah it worked out!! what a fix!
